# What's the difference between constitutive laws and equation of state?

Tags: thermodynamics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, solid-mechanics

While defining material properties in finite element modeling, when should we opt for [constitutive models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutive_equation), such as Linear Elastic or Neohookean (that relate stresses and strains) over Equation of State, such as [Mie-Gruneisen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie%E2%80%93Gr%C3%BCneisen_equation_of_state) (that relate pressure to volume)?

Comment: Mechanical equation of state and constitutive equation are typically considered synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this question the context of relativistic hydrodynamics (RH).

While in the **non-relativistic** case, we use the "Navier-Stokes + continuity" equations to describe the dynamics of $\vec{v}$ and $\rho$ of a fluid,
in a **relativistic settingI answer this question in analogy with "relativistic hydrodynamics".

$\bullet$ In the non-relativistic hydro, we use the "Navier-Stokes + continuity" equations to describe the dynamics of $\vec{v}$ and $\rho$ of the fluid

$\bullet$ In a relativistic setting, we use $u^{\mu}(x)$ and $T(x)$ as dynamic variables. ($x=(t,\vec{x})$). Since $u^{\mu}u_{\mu}=-1$, then it has 3 independent components; there are 4 dynamic variables in total.
However, the RH equations are the equations of conservation of energy (density) and momentum (density):
$$\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=F^{\nu}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
where $F^{\nu}$ is the external force.
**This is kind of relativistic version of the equation you wrote.**

Here $T^{\mu\nu}$ is a rank-2 symmetric tensor, typically with 10 independent components. Thus we have
$$4 \ne 10 \,\,\,!\, ! \,! $$
At this point we need to understand the main ideas of fluid mechanics:
$$\textbf{In a local equilibrium state or close to a local equilibrium state, when the wavelength of the disturbance in the fluid is long,}\\
\textbf{
   $T^{\mu\nu}$ is a function of the local thermal variables $u^{\mu}(x)$ and $T(x)$ and their derivatives. }$$
This is actually the expression of the *derivative expansion*. Now we can introduce the **constitutive relation** of $T^{\mu\nu}$ in the derivative expansion:
$$T^{\mu\nu}=T^{\mu\nu}_{0}+T^{\mu\nu}_{1}+\cdots$$
here

1. $T^{\mu\nu}_{0}$ is the zeroth order in the derivative:
   $$ T_{0}^{\mu\nu}(x)= (\epsilon(x)+ p(x))u^{\mu}(x)u^{\nu}(x)+p( x) \eta^{\mu\nu}$$
   Where $\epsilon(x)$, $p(x)$ are energy density and pressure.
2. $T^{\mu\nu}_{1}$ is the first order in the derivative: ($\zeta$ is the bulk viscosity)
   $$ T_{1}^{\mu\nu}(x)= - \zeta\,\partial\cdot u(x) \eta^{\mu\nu}+\text{Shear viscosity term}$$

So far, we have clarified the "constitutive relations", up to first order in derivatives, in RH theory. However, one might ask:
$$\textbf{The above constitutive relations describe the hydrodynamic regime in what system? }$$
The answer is "any system". But the point is, if we substitute $T^{\mu\nu}_{0}$ and $T^{\mu\nu}_{1}$ above into equation $(1)$, we end up with $4$ equations for $5$ variables (the three components of $u^{\mu}(x)$, $\epsilon(x)$ and $p(x)$)! ! !

It’s time to apply the Equation of State (EoS). It can be like $\epsilon=\epsilon(p)$. Use this equation locally

1. The system of equations is closed.
2. We fall into the hydrodynamic description of a special system with a given EoS.

Hope this helps.